# python connection is not saving data in database

Tags: python, mysql

I have connected to database in python successfully but it is not saving the data I provide.Here is the code :

```
    try:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="traffic_alert")
except Exception as e:
    print('Not connected')


   cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into data (main_status,extracted_info,time) values (%s,%s,%s)",[sentence,final_result,time])
print(sentence)
print(final_result)
print(time)
```

it can successfully print sentence, final_result and time but not saving them in database.sentence,final_result and time are less than 50 characters.I have created the database manually in mysql with these rows :

```
id -> auto_increment,pk
main_status -> varchar(255)
extracted_info -> varchar(255)
seen  -> int(10),Null=True
time ->varchar(255)
```

Comment: I presume copy/paste or formatting error, but your opening `try` indentation is off. Also, any error messages either on python or db side perhaps?

Comment: connection.commit() is the solution. Then it saved in database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
connection.commit()
```

After 
cursor.execute